# EPL Issue on CentOS 5.8

Tags: centos, rpm, epl

I am trying to install R on a CentOS 5.8 64 bit machine.  I am trying to get the rpm, but I get an error message of "unknown or unexpected error".  Here is what I'm using sudo rpm -Uvh http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/5/i386/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm

Comment: For anyone else with this error.  Here is a link to a fix.

http://www.geekdevs.com/2011/09/solved-fedora-release-conflicts-with-epel-release-5-4-noarch-on-fedora-15/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is where I found the answer to my issue.  http://www.geekdevs.com/2011/09/solved-fedora-release-conflicts-with-epel-release-5-4-noarch-on-fedora-15/